# Alternative installation source for QPython Plugin for Tasker

Tags: tasker, python

I am trying to get the QPython Plugin for Tasker from the UK Google Play but despite using voucher credit, it is denied. The creator's email address is not valid.

So I am wondering if anybody has a compiled APK using files from GitHub Qpython Tasker, I do not know how to compile these. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I only found [this GitHub Repo](https://github.com/nmweizi/qpython-plugins-for-tasker) which may not be the same as the Play Store version (e.g. different label on Tasker). Do you know the correct GitHub repo?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply,  that github repo is the only one I could find also, but beyond me at present to create an apk and try it out